# Find current date in a date range string for form select

Tags: javascript, forms, date, selected

Hi there this is a tricky one :)

I have a json object from which i create a select form field this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.vpcourse[0].items.length; i++) {
    $('#kw').append('<option value="'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'">'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'</option>');
    console.log(jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum);
}
```

my problem: the last option which gets added is selected but i need the option select in which date range the actual date is like so:

```
<option value="07.10.2013-01.11.2013">07.10.2013-01.11.2013</option>
<option value="09.09.2013-04.10.2013">09.09.2013-04.10.2013</option>
<option value="12.08.2013-06.09.2013">12.08.2013-06.09.2013</option>
<option value="15.07.2013-09.08.2013" selected="selected">15.07.2013-09.08.2013</option>
<option value="17.06.2013-12.07.2013">17.06.2013-12.07.2013</option>
<option value="20.05.2013-14.06.2013">20.05.2013-14.06.2013</option>
<option value="22.04.2013-17.05.2013">22.04.2013-17.05.2013</option>
<option value="25.03.2013-19.04.2013">25.03.2013-19.04.2013</option>
```

the best way would be to directly check within the for loop if the actual date is inside that date range "07.10.2013-01.11.2013" for example and add selected="selected" to that append.

is this somehow possible!?

**UPDATE:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.vpcourse[0].items.length; i++)
{

        // testDate looks like: 29.12.2014-23.01.2015
        var testDate = jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum;
        var n=testDate.split("-");
        var x = n[0].split(".");
        var y = n[1].split(".");
        var smaller = new Date(x[2], x[1], x[0]);
        var bigger = new Date(y[2], y[1], y[0]);
        var today = new Date();
    if (smaller <= today && today <= bigger) {
        $('#kw').append('<option value="'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'" selected="selected">'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'</option>');
    } else {
        $('#kw').append('<option value="'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'">'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'</option>');
    }
    //console.log(jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum);
}
```

Works 90% :D it selects this:

```
<option value="12.08.2013-06.09.2013">12.08.2013-06.09.2013</option>
<option value="15.07.2013-09.08.2013">15.07.2013-09.08.2013</option>
<option value="17.06.2013-12.07.2013" selected="selected">17.06.2013-12.07.2013</option>
<option value="20.05.2013-14.06.2013">20.05.2013-14.06.2013</option>
```

but instead it should be one option later, so whats wrong ? :(

UPDATE 2:

It works, the issue was that i had to -1 from the month variable...

**WORKING EXAMPLE:**

```
var today = new Date();             
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.vpcourse[0].items.length; i++)
{
        var testDate = jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum;
        var n=testDate.split("-");
        var x = n[0].split(".");
        var y = n[1].split(".");
        var smaller = new Date(x[2], x[1]-1, x[0]);
        var bigger = new Date(y[2], y[1]-1, y[0]);
    if (smaller <= today && today <= bigger) {
        $('#kw').append('<option value="'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'" selected="selected">'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'</option>');
    } else {
        $('#kw').append('<option value="'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'">'+jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum+'</option>');
    }
    //console.log(jsonData.vpcourse[0].items[i].datum);
}
```

Thx goes to LightStyle :)

Comment: Just create three `Date` objects, two for the range and one for the current value. Then check if the milliseconds of the current value are between the first date's ms and the last date's ms.

Comment: I had that idea too, but how do i create a date object from a string lik this: "17.06.2013" ??

Comment: Split the date by `.`, then create the Date object using the year - month - date constructor, like this: `new Date(year, month, day)`. The split will look like `date.split('.')` and then access it with `[0]` for day, `[1]` for month and `[2]` for year.

Comment: tried it your way but it does not work as it should :(

Comment: i updated my question look it :)

Comment: UPDATED my Question with the final working solution :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that months in JS go from 0 to 11(since they are indexed), it was the problem right?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very elegant solution for you, which is very clean to understand, but my advice is to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) as a plugin helper for handle the dates, and a simple plugin which is called [moment-range.js](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) to calculate the ranges for you.

With these plugins, your code could be stripped down to this:

```
// Coming from json or whatever...
var dates = ["07.10.2013-01.11.2013",
"09.09.2013-04.10.2013",
"12.08.2013-06.09.2013",
"15.07.2013-09.08.2013",
"17.06.2013-12.07.2013",
"20.05.2013-14.06.2013",
"22.04.2013-17.05.2013",
"25.03.2013-19.04.2013"];

$(dates).map(function(i,item) {
    // Split the dates
    var datesSplit = item.split("-");

    // Define dates and range
    var start = moment(datesSplit[0], "DD.MM.YYYY");
    var end = moment(datesSplit[1], "DD.MM.YYYY");
    var today = moment();
    var range = moment().range(start, end);

    // Create Option
    var option = $("<option>").text(item);

    // Add parameter when today within range
    if (today.within(range)) {
        option.attr("selected", "selected");
    }

    $("select").append(option);
});
```

I don't think that you would get code that is easier to understand and maintain. Here is the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx67s/).